# Autolaunched Flow Sending Email

Tags: visual-workflow, automated-process, process-automation

Does the Process Automation profile have access to send emails? My autolaunched scheduled flow just ends silently without sending emails or error messages.

I tried creating a dummy automated flow to test it, and it's not going. The dummy flow literally just launches, creates a dummy record, then is supposed to send me an email saying "I'm working." 3 elements. When I run it manually, everything works. When I schedule it to run and let it autolaunch, the dummy record is created but the email is not sent. What could be going on with this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Oddly, the system seems inconsistent in whether or not it'll go. In my main flow, I added an email item at the very beginning that says "The flow started". Randomly, twice I think since I posted this question, I've gotten that email.